# Get image via POST and crop it

Tags: php, gd

I have software, that 'sends' an images via POST to php-script on server. And i have to crop every this picture. So there 2 steps: get it with Curl and crop. But croping section **doesn't work** (Curl section works well and saving image).

`

```
// 1. GET IMAGES VIA POST
    $imgpath = $_POST['img_url']; 
    $dirname = $_POST['img_folder'];
    $imgid = $_POST['imgid'];
    $ch = curl_init($imgpath);
    $fn = ($imgid.substr($imgpath,strrpos($imgpath,'/')+1,strlen($imgpath)));
    $fn = str_replace('?', '_', $fn);
    $fn = str_replace('=', '_', $fn);
    if (is_dir($dirname)==FALSE) mkdir($dirname);
    $fp = fopen($dirname.'/'.$fn, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
// 2. CROP IMAGE
    $in_filename = $_POST['img_url'];
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);
    $offset_x = 0;
    $offset_y = 0;
    $new_height = $height - 40;
    $new_width = $width;
    $out_filename = $in_filename . '_crop';
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($in_filename);
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($new_image, $out_filename);
    imagedestroy($new_image);
    echo($dirname.'/'.$fn);`
```

Comment: Do you have PHP GD installed on your server?

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Yes, GD is installed. Crop works well when i trying to run its 'manually' for 1 image

Comment: No need to use `str_replace()` multiple times. It accepts arrays for the `$search` and `$replacement` parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Also, is this `$_POST['img_url']` to be trusted? An attacker could easily have your sever do its bidding by entering non-image URLs.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I using this script once - when doing a website - then will delete it, so not to worry

Answer (score 1):

Use this function for cropping images, it works for me:

```
<?php

 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 function cropPics($img, $x, $y, $width, $height) {

    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height);
    imagedestroy($src);

 cropPics('images/'.$_GET['i'], (int)$_GET['x'], (int)$_GET['y'], (int)$_GET['w'], (int)$_GET['h']);

?>
```